# how to postback parent page after modal dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, showmodaldialog

I am showing my modaldialog like that:

```
<script>
    function fnOpen() {
        window.showModalDialog("CopyPasteWizard.aspx", "", "dialogHeight: 500px; dialogWidth: 800px; resizable: off; scroll:off;")
    };
</script>
```

In my parent page I call that js function and my dialog opens. I need that when dialog closed, dialog caller parent page should be postback.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dialog close event, try the following:-

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: not in my dialog close event but next line where I call showModalDialog function it works.